# Call to a member function groupBy() on int

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Me gustaria saber si me pueden ayudar a convertir un query a eloquent.

Lo estoy intentando pero me marca un error

> message: "Call to a member function groupBy() on int"

El query que trato de hacer es el siguiente:

```
SELECT count(type_piece), created_at FROM capturepiece WHERE project_guid = '4dde7686-af27-4f1d-90d8-e17c32a2d0b7' AND type_piece = 'Buena' GROUP BY created_at;
```

y yo lo tengo de la siguiente manera en laravel:

```
InsertPiece::select('type_piece', 'created_at')->where('project_guid', $id)->where('type_piece', 'Buena')->count('type_piece')->groupBy('created_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que el método count() te va a devolver únicamente un valor numérico X, entonces sobre este mismo no puedes
aplicar de manera directa la agrupación solicitada.

Lo mas simple es usar el método `selectRaw()` para indicar el uso de la función de agregación:

```
InsertPiece::selectRaw('COUNT(type_piece) AS Conteo, created_at')
    ->whereProjectGuid('4dde7686-af27-4f1d-90d8-e17c32a2d0b7')
    ->whereTypePiece('Buena')
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: siempre que se use el `selectRaw` debo cambiar lo demas poejemplo em este caso el `where('project_guid', $id)` reemplazarlo por `whereProjectGuid`? nunca antes habia visto el query de esa manera, por eso mi duda...

Comment: No, coloqué esa sintaxis por que al método `where` le podemos agregar el nombre de la columna y pasar solo en los paréntesis el argumento para evaluar la igualdad, pero no estan vinculados que si usas selectRaw entonces debas poner los where como lo coloqué, prueba a escribirlos de la manera regular que los conoces e igual van a funcionar @cesdav

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y explicacion, me ayudo en lo que necesitab!

Comment: @BetaM seria bueno agregar ese dato como extra en la respuesta y no dejarlo como un comentario